# Save and restore backlight on hot shutdown

Tags: shutdown, systemd, backlight

I have a system on which we regularly perform a "hot" shutdown - plug out the power without issuing a shutdown command. The problem is that the backlight doesn't get saved and restored correctly. Looking at the systemd backlight service documentation (and the code) https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-backlight@.service.html, it looks like the backlight status will only be stored on shutdown. How can this be changed to save the status every few seconds or on every change such that it works even if a shutdown command is not issued?

Comment: It’s a good thing that computers don’t yet have consciousness, because they would *hate* being deprived of power mid-stream …

Comment: Do not expect your computer to work without issues if you regularly choose to perform a hot shutdown.